# Calculating the residue of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ at the simple pole $z=z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to show that the residue of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ at it's simple pole $z=z_0$ is $\frac{1}{f'(z_0)}$. I have tried using the residue theorem together with Cauchy's integral theorem but not really getting anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

If $f(z)$ has at $z=z_0$ a single pole, then

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}\Res(f,z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)\tag1$$

Now in your case, since $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ has a pole at $z=z_0$, then $f(z_0)=0$, that is, $f(z)$ has a zero at $z=z_0$. Then, if we substitute in $(1)$ $f$ by $\frac{1}{f}$, we get

$$\Res\left(\frac{1}{f},z_0\right)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{z-z_0}{f(z)}$$

And since $f(z_0)=0$,

$$\Res\left(\frac{1}{f},z_0\right)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{z-z_0}{f(z)}=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{z-z_0}{f(z)-f(z_0)}=\frac{1}{f'(z_0)}$$
As desired.